# Scrapy scrape Apple site

Tags: python, scrapy

I have tried to get the Models and also price from the link below, but no luck, would you please let me know what is wrong and how I can scrape these 2 part ?

https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-pro

### here what I have tried:
From $799

To Get Word "From"

`response.xpath('//span[@class="as-price-currentprice"]/text()').extract()`

`[]`

---

To get the price itself:

`response.xpath('//span[@class="nowrap"]/text()').extract()`

`[u'1\u2011800\u2011MY\u2011APPLE.', u'1\u2011800\u2011MY\u2011APPLE.', u'Visit an ', u'call ', u', or ']`

---

**Model**

By the way I am not able to get the models at all

**11-inch iPad Pro**

**12.9-inch iPad Pro**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do that:

```
headers = response.css('.pd-billboard-subheader::text').getall()
prices = response.css('.pd-billboard-price::text').getall()

result = []
for header, price in zip(headers, prices):
    header_cleaned = header.replace('\xa0', ' ')
    price_cleaned = price.replace('\n', '').replace('        ', '').strip()
    result.append([header_cleaned, price_cleaned])
```

After this, result will be equal to something like:

```
[['12.9-inch iPad Pro', 'From $999'],
 ['11-inch iPad Pro', 'From $799'],
 ['10.5-inch iPad Pro', 'From $649'],
 ['iPad', 'From $329'],
 ['iPad mini 4', 'From $399']]
```

Comment: Hi stasdeep, thanks for your quick prompt, actually your code is working fine, but I am wondering what is wrong with my code? I have did it based on the documentation and I have my Amazon spider is working fine, but in apple.com I couldn't get the one as mentioned above ?

Comment: @mos probably your problem was that you were looking not at the response itself, but at the processed HTML. If the answer above helped you, then please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the raw HTML that is being returned back by the website (right-click > View Source).

[image: Raw HTML]

As you can see, the page is just a template that is dynamically rendered by some Javascript code.

When you look at your web browser developer tools, the Javascript is already executed so you see the final rendered HTML, so make sure you look at the raw HTML.

Comment: How to look at the raw html ? because usually we right click on the element on the page and the inspect, to see what we should search for in the scrapy spider.

Comment: Right click > inspect does not give the raw HTML, it gives the rendered one after Javascript execution. You need to right click > view source, or View > View Source, depending on your browser